# BibLaTeX’s supercite superscript reference above punctuation

Tags: biblatex, kerning

I’d like to have the superscript numbers for citation when using `\autocite{}` on top of the punctuation sign (comma or full stop only; obviously it won’t work properly with exclamation or quotation marks) instead of next to it. I saw that way of formatting superscript references at [Siarhei Khirevich's site](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/footnote_citation/) under the section *Superscripts and punctuation* and liked the look of the outcome.

What would be the best/easiest way—ideally without having to use a new command instead of `\autocite`—to achieve that?
Bonus question: Is the same possible for the `\footnote` command and references thereof?

### MWE

#### test.tex

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is not the greatest example in the world---this is just a tribute.\autocite{A01}

The peculiar thing is this, my friend, the greatest example doesn't actually look anything like this one\autocite{B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

#### test.bib

```
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
```

### Output

[image: Screenshot showing that reference number is next to full stop instead of on top]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the autopunct facilities of `\autocite`. Which means it can only be used for `\autocite` and not `\footcite`. It would not be too difficult to also do this for `\footcite`, but it would require more works in the internals (see also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/733 - to be fair though, this solution already meddles with the internals enough). The code here works for `autocite=superscript`, but the same strategy could also be applied to `autocite=footnote`.

You can define which punctuation marks have subsequent footnotes moved with `\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct`. In the example below only `.` and `,` have their footnotes moved as defined with `\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct{.,{,}}`. The starred version `\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct*` resets the list of punctuation before adding the new ones while the unstarred `\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct` always appends its argument to the existing list.

The footnote is not moved the exact length of the punctuation mark but only 80% of it. You can adjust this value as you see fit.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\blx@fnpct@movefor}{}
\newcommand*{\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\let\blx@fnpct@movefor\@empty}
    {}
  \blx@def@fnpct@movefor}
\newcommand*{\blx@def@fnpct@movefor}{%
  \def\do##1{\blx@thecheckpunct{\listadd{\blx@fnpct@movefor}}##1}%
  \docsvlist}

\DeclareFootnoteMovePunct{.,{,}}

\newlength{\blx@fnpct@movelength}
\newcommand*{\blx@fnpct@footnotemover}[1]{%
  #1%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\blx@fnpct@movefor}
    {\settowidth{\blx@fnpct@movelength}{#1}%
     \hspace{-.8\blx@fnpct@movelength}}
    {}%
}

\protected\csedef{blx@acitei@superscript}#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@citeinit
    \noexpand\blx@fnpct@footnotemover{#5}%
    \blxcitecmd{supercite#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{}%
  \endgroup}%
\protected\csedef{blx@macitei@superscript}#1#2#3{%
  \noexpand\blx@fnpct@footnotemover{#3}%
  #1{#2}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}.

Ipsum\autocite{nussbaum,worman}.

Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}, ipsum.
Dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}!

Lorem\autocite{worman} ipsum dolor sit amet. Ipsum\autocite{nussbaum}foo.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]